# how to pass user id intent from itemview click listener

Tags: android

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_list);

        Resources res = getResources();
       // contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.customer_recyclerview);
       /* lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        action=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.action);*/

        // Session class instance
        session = new com.example.admin.myapplication.SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        TextView username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);

        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       /* *
         * Call this function whenever you want to check user login
         * This will redirect user to LoginActivity is he is not
         * logged in
         * */
        session.checkLogin();

        // get user data from session
        HashMap<String, String> userProfile = session.getUserDetails();
        // name
        String name = userProfile.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME);

        // displaying userProfile data
        username.setText(Html.fromHtml("" + name + "</b>"));

       GetCustomers();
    }


    public void GetCustomers(){
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CustomerActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
        // get user data from session
        HashMap<String, String> userProfile = session.getUserDetails();
        String userId =  userProfile.get(SessionManager.Login_ID_PREF);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url+userId,

                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        arrayList.clear();
                        Log.e("RESPONSE", response);

                        try {
                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("order");
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jo = array.getJSONObject(i);

                               customerId= jo.getString("customer_id");
                                CustomerPojo pojo = new CustomerPojo();

                                pojo.setOrderid(jo.getString("order_id"));
                                pojo.setCustomername(jo.getString("customer_fullname"));
                                pojo.setProduct(jo.getString("order_product"));
                                pojo.setQuentity(jo.getString("order_quantity"));
                                pojo.setPaid(jo.getString("order_amount"));
                                arrayList.add(pojo);

                                SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("pref",MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
                                editor.putString("customer_id",customerId);
                                Log.e(TAG,"Customerid---"+customerId);
                                editor.apply();
                                Toast.makeText(CustomerActivity.this, "Customerid"+customerId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                            // Dismiss the progress dialog
                            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                                pDialog.dismiss();

                            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                            //Collections.reverse(orderList);  display data from reverse last in first show
                            customerAdapter = new CustomerAdapter(context,arrayList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(customerAdapter);
                            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            customerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                           /* rvInbox.addItemDecoration(new MyDividerItemDecoration(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,16));
                            rvInbox.setAdapter(inboxAdapter);*/

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(CustomerActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id=item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {

            case R.id.profile:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.logout:
                session.logoutUser();
                Toast.makeText(this, "logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }



    public class CustomerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomerAdapter.Holder> {

        ArrayList<CustomerPojo> arrayList;
        Context context;

        public CustomerAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<CustomerPojo> arrayList){

            this.arrayList=arrayList;
            this.context=context;
        }
        @Override
        public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.customer_list, parent, false);
            return new Holder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int i) {

            CustomerPojo pojo=arrayList.get(i);

            holder.txtOrderid.setText(pojo.getOrderid());
            holder.txtCustomername.setText(pojo.getCustomername());
            holder.txtProduct.setText(pojo.getProduct());
            holder.txtQuentity.setText(pojo.getQuentity());
            holder.txtPaid.setText(pojo.getPaid());
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {

               /* Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),CustomerViewActivity.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);*/

                    final String[] listItems = {"View","Deactive","Edit","Order","Billing"};

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                    builder.setTitle("Choose item");

                    //----------------------Pass next Activity -----------------------------//


                    builder.setItems(listItems, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if (which == 0){
```

/* i was pass intent into customerId but i was get every time same customer id */

```
Intent intent=new 

Intent(v.getContext(),CustomerViewActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("CustomerID",customerId);
                                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "View"+customerId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                else if (which == 1){
                                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Deactive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                else if (which == 2){
                                    Intent intent=new Intent(context,CustomerEditActivity.class);
                                    context.startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                else if (which == 3){
                                    Intent intent=new Intent(context,CustomerOrderActivity.class);
                                    context.startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                else if (which == 4){
                                    Intent intent=new Intent(context,CustomerBillingActivity.class);
                                    context.startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                //Toast.makeText(CustomerActivity.this, "Position: " + which + " Value: " + listItems[which], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });

                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                });
            }



            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return arrayList.size();
            }

            public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
                TextView txtOrderid,txtCustomername,txtProduct,txtQuentity,txtPaid;
                public Holder(View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);

                    txtOrderid=itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
                    txtCustomername=itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                    txtProduct=itemView.findViewById(R.id.product);
                    txtQuentity=itemView.findViewById(R.id.qunty);
                    txtPaid=itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `intent.putExtra("CustomerID",customerId);`

Try this `intent.putExtra("CustomerID",pojo.getCustomerId()); //or whatever is the method name`

Answer (score 0):

Hil, welcome to StackOverflow.

Another way to call intent with bundle/extras is to place your intent inside your RecylerViewHolder class, you could try this:

```js
public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  TextView txtOrderid, txtCustomername, txtProduct, txtQuentity, txtPaid;
  public Holder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), YourActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString("CustomerID", txtCustomerId.getText().toString().trim());

        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);

      }
    });
    ...
  }
}
```

And in your destination activity, let's call it YourActivity.class, you can add this code to get extras by adding this code:

```js
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_krs_detail);

  TextView output;

  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  output.setText(bundle.getString("CustomerID"));

  ...

}
```

Hope this helps,
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change in parsing value in `Intent` for CustomerID get values from **pojo**

**Replace**

```
Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),CustomerViewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("CustomerID",customerId);
v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

**To**

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),CustomerViewActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("CustomerID",pojo.customerId);
 v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

In your case, you also try this

```
Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),CustomerViewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("CustomerID",txtOrderid,getText().toString());
v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    arrayList.clear();
                    Log.e("RESPONSE", response);

                    try {
                        //converting the string to json array object
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("order");
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jo = array.getJSONObject(i);

                           customerId= jo.getString("customer_id"); // problem is here
                            CustomerPojo pojo = new CustomerPojo();
```

here instead of storing customerId create new field in CustomerPojo as customerId then create getter and setter then set the value in pojo

```
pojo.setCustomerId(jo.getString("customer_id"))
```

Then in the bindViewHolder

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int i) {
        CustomerPojo pojo=arrayList.get(i);
      //  pojo.getCustomerId(); this will return your current selected customerId
```

So

```
 builder.setItems(listItems, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (which == 0){

                        Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),CustomerViewActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("CustomerID",pojo.getCustomerId());
```

here what is cause error is you set the customer id in a local variable in bindVeiwHolder so it has the value of last bind customerId from the response list.

Comment: Enjoy coding :)